# Why are my vector<int>s not defaulting to 0?

Tags: c++

The below code works fine on ideone, gives an output of

```
10000
10000
```

as expected

However on my local machine, the output is of the sort

```
9990
9998
```

All the code does is create a vector of 10k `int`'s and count the number of 0's in it. Once using a class, and once in main.

If I run the code locally in debug mode, it results in

```
0
0
```

I'm using codeBlocks on Windows 7 with the default GNU GCC Compiler (though it compiles C++, so I guess its different than the Linux GCC which does only C)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class vecttest
{
    vector<int> vect;
    public:
    vecttest()
    {
        vect.reserve(10000);
    }
    int zcount()
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            if(vect[i]==0)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
};
int main()
{
    vecttest v;
    cout<<v.zcount();

    vector<int> v2;
    v2.reserve(10000);
    int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            if(v2[i]==0)
                count++;
        }
    cout<<endl<<count;
}
```

ideone link: http://ideone.com/q1XRvQ

Comment: Why do you think it should default to zero? You are just reserving space

Comment: @EdHeal thats the behaviour mentioned in the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222404/c-value-of-uninitialized-vectorint

Comment: You should use `vect.resize(10000,0);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, that did it..  now I see that reserve doesnt initialize, resize does

Comment: @Akash - reserve is just changing capacity. Resize changes the amount allocated

Comment: Akash, check out https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html and add `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to the compiler commandline. This would possibly have told you that you are doing something wrong before asking here.

Answer (score 2):

The method reserve(..) only guarantees that the space is allocated. It does not guarantee the values in the elements of the vector. The only thing that will happen is that your counting will not crash. The resulting value is implementation/allocation/etc dependent.

The core idea that is necessary to understand about containers and iterators is that they are the same insecure as simple arrays:

```
char b1[100];
vector<char> b2(100);

void f()
{
   char c1 = b1[200];
   char c2 = b2[300];
}
```

In both cases compiler will generate code that will pick up something outside of the array. Both examples trigger undefined behavior. Maybe the code will crash, maybe not. Both accesses are equally bad.

The main reason for such design is speed. Access to array should be fast. This is core idea of C/C++. The value of the index is the responsibility of the programmer. Compiler will not check. Like it or not, this is so.

Comment: The counting isn't even guaranteed to not crash. Reading from outside the actual size of the vector is undefined behaviour. (As is interpreting an un-constructed memory region as an `int`, by some interpretations of the strict aliasing rules).

Comment: Very strictly speaking you are right. I can bet any amount that there is no non debug implementation what will crash. Debug implementation will throw exception...

Comment: Debug implementations will very surely not throw exceptions, as exceptions are for normal error handling. With undefined behaviour, you want to abort execution so that the programmer can fix the code, but it's not something that your process could recover from.